# Carousel Slider is not working in Angular 8 while using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

> I'm Currently working on Angular 8. My slider works fine with static
> data. But when I try to loop through some data, my 'left' and 'right'
> buttons don't work. And I'm unable to scroll those pictures. Im getting my images using *ngfor. I've seen many solutions around. But no one was able to solve my issue. Any help
> would be very much appreciated. Thank You

**My HTML Code**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
            <div class="carousel-inner row w-10 mxauto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active" *ngFor="let reward of readableRewards">
                    <img src="{{reward?.Image}}" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-bloc" alt="slide 1">
                </div>

            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**MY JS Code**

```
      $('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);

var idx = $e.index();
console.log("IDX :  " + idx);

var itemsPerSlide = 8;
var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction=="left") {
            $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        }
        else {
            $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        }
    }
}
});
```

**My CSS Code**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
      display: block;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
      transition: none;
      margin-right: initial;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -33.3333%;
      z-index: -1;
      display: block;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
      visibility: visible;
  }

  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      display: block;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
      visibility: visible;
      display: block;
      visibility: visible;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not an answer but a path that will help you find the answer. since I can't write comments but I can write answers, I'll write here. since the slider works correctly without getting data, the problem is getting data. this section of code is not shown. but if it causes an error, then further execution may be suspended because of it. view or display the messages in the console and the code that generates the data so that they can help you.